# Getting empty value for output from a previous job in a new one in a GitHub Action

Tags: github-actions

```
on: pull_request

jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: [re-centos7]
    # Map a step output to a job output
    outputs:
      output1: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.test }}
      output2: ${{ steps.step2.outputs.test }}
    steps:
      - id: step1
        run: echo "test=world1" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - id: step2
        run: echo "test=world" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
  job2:
    runs-on: [re-centos7]
    needs: job1
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{needs.job1.outputs.output1}}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbUh2.png)

I'm trying to use the job's output in the next job. I'm trying to use github output for this but I see it's getting an empty value for the output. Can someone help? Thanks!
output is empty for ${{needs.job1.outputs.output1}}

Comment: Are you using runners from github.com itself, or self-hosted runners locally?

Comment: I'm using self-hosted runners which are integrated with Kubernetes cluster

Comment: Did you try with `$GITHUB_OUTPUT` instead of `$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT`?

Comment: Yep, `$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT` is for powershell, while this action apparently uses `[re-centos7]` and therefore bash as default shell

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using self-hosted runners which are integrated with Kubernetes cluster

The first thing to check is the version of your self-hosted runners: The deprecation of set-output was [mentioned recently (oct. 2022)](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/)

> If you are using self-hosted runners make sure they are updated to version 2.297.0 or greater.

If the version is lower, that would explain the empty values.

Comment: I'm using RUNNER-VERSION 2.298.2 but still getting an empty value.
What is the suggested runner version to use to not get an empty value

Comment: @SwathiDA What is your GHES (GitHub for Enterprise Server) version?

Comment: GitHub Enterprise Server 3.6.3

Comment: @SwathiDA That should be recent enough (unless [GHES 3.7](https://github.blog/2022-11-08-github-enterprise-server-3-7-is-now-generally-available/) brings something specific to this feature).